# Distinguish read and unread messages in kafka

Tags: hbase, apache-zookeeper, apache-storm, apache-kafka

Is there any way how we can find

- the offset or timestamp from where the messages are yet to be consumed
- the last timestamp which has been consumed

or to distinguish the read and unread messages in kafka using storm

Comment: try to put some more details e.g which version of kafka (there are hell lot of changes between the current and previous one regarding the handling * consuming the messages) , what API you are using to consume. Put down some code you are trying currently. Those help others to get to the issue more quickly.

Answer (score 3):

[**Finding Starting Offset for Reads**](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/0.8.0+SimpleConsumer+Example)

> Now define where to start reading data. Kafka includes two constants
>   to help, kafka.api.OffsetRequest.EarliestTime() finds the beginning of
>   the data in the logs and starts streaming from there,
>   kafka.api.OffsetRequest.LatestTime() will only stream new messages.
>   Don’t assume that offset 0 is the beginning offset, since messages age
>   out of the log over time.

The doc explains in detail the offset handling using the Simple Consumer API. You should probably find what you are looking for.

If you are having issue dealing with the message offset  try to share some code snippet. It helps understand the problem in a much better way. Or If you just curious to know the concept then you should probably go through the [documentation](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation.html) and the [wiki](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/Index) page first.

Comment: the question is similar to [QUESTION HERE](http://grokbase.com/t/kafka/users/12cherxwf5/fetch-messages-since-a-specific-time).